# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.bcurre.bconvert/files/libroyalfrencharchitect.so" has bad ELF magic: 3c21444f

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    Process: com.bcurre.bconvert, PID: 15051
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.bcurre.bconvert/files/libroyalfrencharchitect.so" has bad ELF magic: 3c21444f
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:929)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1625)
        at com.bcurre.bconvert.api.LoaderApiClient.lambda$loadNativeLib$1(LoaderApiClient.java:77)
        at com.bcurre.bconvert.api.-$$Lambda$LoaderApiClient$no9_-A5nZsIWK_uFv-_aOGoGt6w.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

how to solve this problem I also try abiFilters = ['x86', 'x86_64','armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'] but still this error showing.

```
private static void loadNativeLib(String requestedFile, String nativeVariant, String path){

        new Thread(() -> {

            try {
                Response response = MainActivity.retrofitClient.create(LoaderApiInterface.class)
                        .getFile(nativeVariant).execute();

                ResponseBody responseBody = (ResponseBody) response.body();

                String dirPath = path + "/" + requestedFile;
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dirPath);
                fileOutputStream.write(responseBody.bytes());
                System.out.println(dirPath.toString());
                System.load(dirPath);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to start loader due to the native lib not being loaded");
            }
        }).start();
```

This is the code. In System.load(dirPath); it shows the error. How to fix that?

Comment: That `.so` library file is probably not built for Android architectures. If you have the file and a linux terminal shell, then run `file libraryfile.so` and see what output you get.

Comment: The path `.../files/` shows that the problematic library is not included in the standard libs folder within your APK file. Thus your `abiFilters `has no effect on this library. Try to find out where this library comes from and why it is stored in the wrong location (I assume it has been extracted or downloaded from somewhere). AFAIK loading so files from /data/data is not possible on recent Android versions anymore.

Comment: /data/data is not possible then now what will be the possible path,any idea.that will help me